# Does yarn have an equivalent to unsafe-perm=true?

Tags: yarnpkg

As far as I understand, I can add a `.npmrc` file to the root of my directory to prevent node packages to be installed as non-root user when using npm.

Is there an equivalent flag, option, or config when using yarn?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `yarn config set unsafe-perm true` to get the equivalent result.

See [Yarn Docs for config set](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/config/set) and [this Github answer](https://github.com/eclipse-theia/theia/issues/508#issuecomment-329116843) explaining that `unsafe-perm` is false by default. Unfortunately, there isn't anything about it in the official docs.